# Evaluate the area of the surface using double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ delimited by $z=0$ and
>   $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I have to say that I found similar posts but none has helped me, some gave me wrong anwears. The surface integral I take always gave me $\pi$ in it. The real anwear is 8. I preffer polar coordinates, but it's ok without.

Comment: I used the curve $(x,y,\sqrt(x^2+y^2))$, evaluated the normal vector and integrated with the boundaries $0<\theta<2\pi$ and $0<r<2cos(\theta)$.

Comment: @GustavoAlvesdeOliveira Why do you use polar coordinates, when your parametrization is clearly not dependant on $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Well,I just ommited the steps. When u take the normal vector, it gives $\sqrt(2)$. Then I use polar coordinates to see the boundaries better.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the normal vector, it's its length.

Comment: @MarkViola "I used the curve (x,y,(√x2+y2))" How is this parametrization dependant on $\theta$ and $r$? This is the so called trivial parametrization. I wasn't saying that he shouldn't use polar coordinates, I was saying that his parametrization isn't in polar coordinates. Hence your answer is by no means related to my comment

Comment: @Stefan4024 I see your point.  Apology for my misunderstanding your intent.  I've deleted my previous comment

Comment: @MarkViola No hard feelings. Anyway nice answer! +1

Comment: @stefan4024 Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface $x^2+y^2=2x$ can be written in polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$ as

$$\rho=2\cos(\phi)$$

where $\phi \in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

---

The vector $\vec r=\hat\rho \rho+\hat zz$ that locates a point on that surface can be written parametrically as

$$\begin{align}
\vec r(\phi,z)&=\hat \rho(\cos(\phi))\rho(\phi)+\hat zz\\\\
&=\hat \rho(\phi)2\cos(\phi)+\hat zz
\end{align}$$

---

The vector surface element $\hat n\,dS$ of this surface is given by

$$\begin{align}
\hat n\,dS&=\left(\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \phi}\times\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial z}\right)\,d\phi\,dz\\\\
&=\left(\left(-2\hat \rho\sin(\phi)+2\hat\phi \cos(\phi)\right)\times \hat z\right)\,d\phi\,dz\\\\
&=\left(2\hat \rho \cos(\phi)+2\hat \theta \sin(\phi)\right)\,d\phi\,dz
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have $dS=2\,d\phi\,dz$.

---

The surface is bounded by the plane $z=0$ and the $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\cos(\phi)$.

---

Finally, we can write

$$\begin{align}
S&=\int_S (1)\,dS\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^\pi/2 \int_0^{2\cos(\phi)}(2)\,dz\,d\phi\\\\
&=4\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(\phi)\,d\phi\\\\
&=8
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: *polar* coordinates -> *cylindrical* coordinates

Comment: @GCab What is the point of your comment?

Comment: I didn't understand some things. Where is the jacobiant determinant of the change of coordinates? Don't I have to integrate the lenght of the normal vector?

Comment: I first try to find the parametric representation, then I get its lenght, then I change to polar coordinates with the jacobian determinant, then I integrate. I'm a bit lost in what you did, but I know it makes sense.

Comment: The Jacobian is embedded already.  We have $dS=2\,d\phi\,dz$.  Note that the Jacobian is the term $|\vec r_\phi \times \vec r_z|=2$

Comment: Ok, and what about the parametrization. I doesn't go directly to R3, I'm not understanding that so well.

Comment: We're on the circular cylinder $\rho=2\cos(\phi)$, where $-\pi/2\le \phi \le \pi/2$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Another thing. I don't understand how you did that vector product. Did you use chain rule?

Comment: When you say at the beginning "can be written in polar coordinates..", it would be more correct to say " .. in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z)$